# Objective-c UIView making a circle can't make multiple ones

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to make multiple circles within a UIView. I can get one to display on the screen but not more. I replaced the circle class with a UILabel and outputted the index of my loop and the logic worked fine, so I'm not sure what the error would be with a UIView subclass. Here's the relevant code:

FEG_Circle (UIView subclass)

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float radius;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor* clrCircle;

- (void) setMyCircle : (UIColor*) clrCircle : (float) radius;
```

.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setMyCircle : (UIColor*) clrCircle : (float) radius {

    _clrCircle = clrCircle;
    _radius = radius;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if(_clrCircle) {


        CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, _clrCircle.CGColor);
        CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, _radius, _radius));


        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
    }

}
```

Heres' where I am calling it:

...

```
UIView* vTopWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-200.0, 50.0, 400.0, 50.0)];
        vTopWrapper.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

        float thisX = 0.0;

        for (int x=0; x<10; x++) {
            FEG_CIRCLE* thisCircle = [[FEG_CIRCLE alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thisX, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0)];
            [vTopWrapper addSubview:thisCircle];
            [thisCircle setMyCircle:FEG_RA_ORANGE :20.0];

            thisX = thisX + 30.0;
        }


        DDLogVerbose(@"%@", vTopWrapper.subviews);

        [self.view addSubview:vTopWrapper];
```

...

Here's the console log:

```
"<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09a790; frame = (0 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09a860>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09aaf0; frame = (30 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09ab60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09abf0; frame = (60 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09ac60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09acf0; frame = (90 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09ad60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09adf0; frame = (120 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09ae60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09aef0; frame = (150 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09af60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09aff0; frame = (180 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09b060>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09b150; frame = (210 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09aa60>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09b220; frame = (240 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09b290>>",
    "<FEG_CIRCLE: 0xa09b320; frame = (270 0; 25 25); layer = <CALayer: 0xa09b390>>"
```

But in my simulator I only see one circle displayed, at the first 30,0 position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling [thisCircle setNeedsDisplay]? Call it after you create thisCircle view.

Comment: Off topic but please take a look at the [Cocoa Naming Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Comment: HAS - can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, you could rename your class like `FEGCircle`, `FEG_RA_ORANGE` looks much like a const, but isn't one and `clrCircle` would be much better to read if it was `circleColor`. Usually you should write the code in a way you would write English. This makes it not only easier for *you* to read but also for other devs (like us) ;-). In the end it's (mainly) code smell but if you want to use KVC/KVO you definitely want to follow those convention (especially camelCase).

Comment: 5 other things: 1. You must not assume that setters and getters are completely initialized in `-[init]`, so do not use them there. Do UI stuff first when `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib`. 2. If you need an `init` method make its return type `(instancetype)` instead of `(id)`. You get a much better code completion. 3. Use the ivar (e.g. `_clrCircle` only in it's accessors (and `init` and `dealloc`. Use `self.clrCircle` instead. 4. `retain` is outdated ;-) - use `strong` instead. 5. When working with UIKit you want to use `CGFloat` instead of `float`. Of course those notes are **NOT** mandatory:)

Comment: Thanks HAS, some of this is a style guide I'm required to use, most objects have a prefix to denote type/class, such as txt for textfield, lbl for labels, etc. FEG_RA_ORANGE is a constant, it's defined in a config file. Didn't know about retain/strong or the instancetype return. Thanks for the code review and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're implementing `-drawRect`, you're only rendering the space *inside* that particular view. This means that the area you want to draw in is the rectangle with an origin at (0,0) with width and height matching the view's bounds. The system takes care of positioning what you draw in the correct place in the parent view.

So, when you do this in your `-drawRect` method:

```
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, _radius, _radius));
```

You're actually drawing the circle *outside* of the view when the frame's origin is not (0,0). You probably want:

```
CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(0, 0, _radius, _radius));
```